# Exempt income and Roth IRA contributions

Tags: united-states, roth-ira, contribution, tax-exemption

So I am a student and will be making less than 6 thousand dollars this year, and so I'll be exempt from taxes. Can I use some of the money I make to contribute to a Roth IRA?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If by exempt, you're just referring to the fact that the income is less than your standard deduction and personal exemption, then yes, that money can be used to fund a Roth. Great time to do it.

To be clear, in 2014 the limit for an under 50 year old, is $5500 ($6500 if 50 or older). Only *earned* income may be used for deposits. No interest, dividends, etc.

Comment: It is worth emphasizing that IRA contributions are limited to the lesser of $5500 and the total "earned income" from salaries, wages, self-employment etc. This needs to be taken into account if any part of that < $6K is from interest or dividends etc.

Comment: Yes! Done. You are always welcome to edit my answers to add such clarifying remarks. Thanks, again.